# Blank $_POST entries not to replace data in MySQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem updating an MySQL Database. I want to be able to update a chart (MySQL Database) as more information comes in, the employees at my firm do not fill in all the information all at once and fill in this chart as more information comes in.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//retrieve our data from POST
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$Date_Received = $_POST['DateReceived'];
$Mortgagee_Vendor = $_POST['Mortgagee'];
$Mortgagor_Purchaser = $_POST['Mortgagor'];
$We_Act_For = $_POST['WeActFor'];
$Amount = $_POST['Amount'];
$Full_Address = $_POST['FullAddress'];
$Lot = $_POST['Lot'];
$Plan = $_POST['Plan'];
$Municipality = $_POST['Municipality'];
$Solicitor = $_POST['Solicitor'];
$Closing_Date = $_POST['ClosingDate'];
$Has_Union = $_POST['Union'];
$Lawyer_Clerk = $_POST['LawyerClerk'];
$Date_File_Opened = $_POST['FileOpened'];
$Search_Date = $_POST['Search'];
$Requisition_Date = $_POST['ReqDate'];
$Requisition_Sub = $_POST['ReqSubmittedReplied'];
$Mortgage_Inst = $_POST['MortgageInst'];
$Appointment_Date = $_POST['AppDate'];
$Payout_Req_Sent = $_POST['PayoutSent'];
$Payout_Req = $_POST['PayoutRequest'];
$Requisition_Recieved = $_POST['ReqReceived'];
$Draft_Deed = $_POST['DraftDeed'];
$Report_Letter = $_POST['ReportLetter'];
$Undertakings = $_POST['Undertakings'];
$File_Closed = $_POST['FileClosed'];
$Special_Notes = $_POST['SpecialNotes'];
$Deal_Active = $_POST['DealActive'];

//connect to database    
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'database';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'Password'; 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

//sanitize all fields

$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($ID); 
$Date_Received = mysql_real_escape_string($Date_Received);
$Mortgagee_Vendor = mysql_real_escape_string($Mortgagee_Vendor);
$Mortgagor_Purchaser = mysql_real_escape_string($Mortgagor_Purchaser);
$We_Act_For = mysql_real_escape_string($We_Act_For);
$Amount = mysql_real_escape_string($Amount);
$Full_Address = mysql_real_escape_string($Full_Address);
$Lot = mysql_real_escape_string($Lot);
$Plan = mysql_real_escape_string($Plan);
$Municipality = mysql_real_escape_string($Municipality);
$Solicitor = mysql_real_escape_string($Solicitor);
$Closing_Date = mysql_real_escape_string($Closing_Date);
$Has_Union = mysql_real_escape_string($Has_Union);
$Lawyer_Clerk = mysql_real_escape_string($Lawyer_Clerk);
$Date_File_Opened = mysql_real_escape_string($Date_File_Opened);
$Search_Date = mysql_real_escape_string($Search_Date);
$Requisition_Date = mysql_real_escape_string($Requisition_Date);
$Requisition_Sub = mysql_real_escape_string($Requisition_Sub);
$Mortgage_Inst = mysql_real_escape_string($Mortgage_Inst);
$Appointment_Date = mysql_real_escape_string($Appointment_Date);
$Payout_Req_Sent = mysql_real_escape_string($Payout_Req_Sent);
$Payout_Req = mysql_real_escape_string($Payout_Req);
$Requisition_Recieved = mysql_real_escape_string($Requisition_Recieved);
$Draft_Deed = mysql_real_escape_string($Draft_Deed);
$Report_Letter = mysql_real_escape_string($Report_Letter);
$Undertakings = mysql_real_escape_string($Undertakings);
$File_Closed = mysql_real_escape_string($File_Closed);
$Special_Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($Special_Notes);
$Deal_Active = mysql_real_escape_string($Deal_Active);

//insert values to mysql database
mysql_query("UPDATE `all_info` SET `Date Received` = '$Date_Received', `Deal Active` = '$Deal_Active', `Mortgagee/Vendor` = '$Mortgagee_Vendor', `Mortgagor/Purchaser` = '$Mortgagor_Purchaser', `We Act For` = '$We_Act_For', `Amount` = '$Amount', `Full Address` = '$Full_Address', `Lot` =  '$Lot', `Plan` = '$Plan', `Municipality` = '$Municipality', `Solicitor` = '$Solicitor', `Closing Date` = '$Closing_Date', `Lawyer/Clerk` = '$Lawyer_Clerk', `File Opened` = '$Date_File_Opened', `Search Date` = '$Search_Date', `Requisition Date` = '$Requisition_Date', `Requisition Submitted/Replied` = '$Requisition_Sub', `Mortgage Instructions Received` = '$Mortgage_Inst', `Appointment Date for Clients` = '$Appointment_Date', `Pay Out Request Sent` = '$Payout_Req_Sent', `Payout/Funding Sent`= '$Payout_Req', `Requisition Received` = '$Requisition_Recieved', `Draft Deed/Adjustment Sent` = '$Draft_Deed', `Reporting Letter` = '$Report_Letter', `Undertaking Satisfied` = '$Undertakings', `File Closed` = '$File_Closed', `Special Notes` = '$Special_Notes' WHERE ID = '$ID'");





echo mysql_error();     

mysql_close();

?>
```

So basically, when a user creates the row (using separate script) he/she will fill in "some" of the post entries. My main problem is when entries exist, they are replaced with blank post submission. I need MySQL to ignore these "blank" post entries and not replace data that exists.

**EDIT:** with the help of arxanas I was able to come up with this code, this is the final product with working code.

```
<?php
$ID = $_POST['ID'] 
$Date_Received = $_POST['DateReceived'];
$Mortgagee_Vendor = $_POST['Mortgagee'];
$Mortgagor_Purchaser = $_POST['Mortgagor'];
$We_Act_For = $_POST['WeActFor'];
$Amount = $_POST['Amount'];
$Full_Address = $_POST['FullAddress'];
$Lot = $_POST['Lot'];
$Plan = $_POST['Plan'];
$Municipality = $_POST['Municipality'];
$Solicitor = $_POST['Solicitor'];
$Closing_Date = $_POST['ClosingDate'];
$Has_Union = $_POST['Union'];
$Lawyer_Clerk = $_POST['LawyerClerk'];
$Date_File_Opened = $_POST['FileOpened'];
$Search_Date = $_POST['Search'];
$Requisition_Date = $_POST['ReqDate'];
$Requisition_Sub = $_POST['ReqSubmittedReplied'];
$Mortgage_Inst = $_POST['MortgageInst'];
$Appointment_Date = $_POST['AppDate'];
$Payout_Req_Sent = $_POST['PayoutSent'];
$Payout_Req = $_POST['PayoutRequest'];
$Requisition_Recieved = $_POST['ReqReceived'];
$Draft_Deed = $_POST['DraftDeed'];
$Report_Letter = $_POST['ReportLetter'];
$Undertakings = $_POST['Undertakings'];
$File_Closed = $_POST['FileClosed'];
$Special_Notes = $_POST['SpecialNotes'];
$Deal_Active = $_POST['DealActive'];

// connect to database
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass'; 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

$fields = array(
    "ID" => "ID",
    "Date Received" => "DateReceived",
    "Mortgagee/Vendor" =>"Mortgagee",
    "Mortgagor/Purchaser" => "Mortgagor",
    "We Act For" => "WeActFor",
    "Amount" => "Amount",
    "Full Address" => "FullAddress",
    "Lot" => "Lot",
    "Plan" => "Plan",
    "Municipality" => "Municipality",
    "Solicitor" => "Solicitor",
    "Closing Date" => "ClosingDate",
    "Union" => "Union",
    "Lawyer/Clerk" => "LawyerClerk",
    "File Opened" => "FileOpened",
    "Search Date" => "Search",
    "Requisition Date" => "ReqDate",
    "Requisition Submitted/Replied" => "ReqSubmittedReplied",
    "Mortgage Instructions Received" => "MortgageInst",
    "Appointment Date for Clients" => "AppDate",
    "Pay Out Request Sent" => "PayoutSent",
    "Payout/Funding Sent" => "PayoutRequest",
    "Requisition Received" => "ReqReceived",
    "Draft Deed/Adjustment Sent" => "DraftDeed",
    "Reporting Letter" => "ReportLetter",
    "Undertaking Satisfied" => "Undertakings",
    "File Closed" => "FileClosed",
    "Special Notes" => "SpecialNotes",
    "Deal Active" => "DealActive",    

);
$update = array();
foreach ($fields as $column => $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field]) && strlen($_POST[$field])) {
        $update[] = "`".$column."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."'";
    }
}
$sql = "UPDATE `all_info` SET ".implode(", ", $update)."WHERE ID = '$ID'";
mysql_query($sql);

echo mysql_error();
echo "<br><br><center>Table Sucessfully Updated</center>";      

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: You're going to have to check each entry in `$_POST`; if there's text in there, then you can add it to your `UPDATE` SQL.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fields = array(
    "ID" => "ID",
    "Date Received" => "DateReceived",
    "Mortgagee/Vendor" =>"Mortgagee",
    ...
);
$update = array();
foreach ($fields as $column => $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field]) && strlen($_POST[$field])) {
        $update[] = "`".$column."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."'";
    }
}
$sql = "UPDATE `all_info` SET ".implode(", ", $update)."WHERE ID = '$ID'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Nice answer!

Comment: Except you'll get an error if a field wasn't POSTed ... `empty` would be a better test than `strlen` in this situation.

Comment: @rdlowrey I use `strlen` instead of `empty` because `empty("0");` returns `true` (you know, in case somebody decides to name their inputs "0"). I will add an `isset`, though.

Comment: Invalid inputs shouldn't be handled at this layer anyway -- if you need to validate types, appropriate measures should be taken elsewhere.

Comment: for some reason the code doesnt work when I add more entires to $fields array(). When I try to run just your code it works

Answer (score -1):

Fairly simple, as you're processing post, you'd have:

```
$values = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
   if (empty($key)) {
       continue;
   }
   $fields[] = mysql_real_escape_string($key) . "='" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "'";
}

$value_list = implode(', ', $fields);
$sql = "UPDATE ... SET " . $value_list;
```

But then this begs the question - what if the user WANTS to empty out a field? This simple code will simply ignore any empty field, and leave the original value intact in the database.

Comment: Using `$_POST` instead of a predefined array opens it up to a mass-assignment vulnerability, and also catches irrelevant POST fields.